# Echo multiple strings from a function in PHP

Tags: php, function

I have tried to create a function that will take two arguments and in theory, echo out the result.  After doing some Googling, I got the impression that this should be accomplished using an array, however I'm not too sure on the logic.

I was hoping I could call the function like so - kb_article("How to do something", "Q12345"), to get the formatting of:

> Related KB Article(s):
>  How to do something - Q12345

```
    function kb_article($title, $code)
{
    echo "<h2>Related KB Article(s): </h2><br />";
    echo $title + " - " + $code;
}
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: That's not how you do string concatenation in PHP - you need to use `.` instead of `+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String concatenation is performed using `.` ( instead of `+` ). Here's the corrected version of your function:

```
function kb_article($title, $code)
{
    echo '<h2>Related KB Article(s):</h2><br />';
    echo $title . " - " . $code;
}
```

Comment: My mistake, used too many languages since I last used PHP!  Thank you for the reply, I would upvote you, however I've recently been downvoted on a previous post and thus I lost the ability to do so! :(

Comment: @DaveMelia, nevermind. Just accept this as answer for future visitors. Also notice that you usually can delete questions that have been down voted (for example [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509275/self-submitting-form-php-undefined-index)) and your reputation will grow back again.

Answer (score 0):

You can just enclose the whole string in double quotes...

```
function kb_article($title, $code)
{
    echo "<h2>Related KB Article(s): </h2><br />";
    echo "$title  -  $code";
}

kb_article("title","code");

// outputs the expected title - code
```

Or as previously posted, do string concatenation properly.

```
function kb_article($title, $code)
{
    echo "<h2>Related KB Article(s): </h2><br />";
    echo  $title . " - " . $code;
}

kb_article("title","code");
```

Comment: Thank you also, I didn't realize I could use them both in the same string!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use . instead of + to concatenate in php. Like so:

echo $title." - ".$code;